# What are the parser techniques implemented in kaitai struct? Does it implement backtracking?

Tags: parsing, backtracking, kaitai-struct

I have to deal with a buffer of bytes. This buffer can have multiple grammars (A, B, C, .. , etc).

For example: AxxxxBxxxxACxxx

where x's are dirty bytes and I would like to skip them. (They don't match any grammar)

I want to know if it is possible to use kaitai-struct to parse those grammars skipping the dirty bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, and it's generally not an objective of Kaitai Struct.

Whole idea of binary parsing is generally very different from classic parsing theory, as binary formats are *designed to be machine-readable* and thus are typically non-ambiguous. Binary parsers typically are very straightforward and do not employ "state", "backtracking", "recursive descent", grammars as a representation of internal state machine, etc.